# Java: Catch a SAXException thrown by method in supertype

Tags: java, inheritance, exception, sax, saxparseexception

I have a class extending `org.xml.sax.ext.DefaultHandler2` in which I override

```
public void startElement(String uri, 
    String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
```

which is originally from `DefaultHandler2`'s supertype `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler`.

When I try to parse an XML file encoded in UTF-8 *with* BOM, it throws an exception

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

as well-documented elsewhere.

Now, I'd like to catch this exception in my code, i.e., my class extending `DefaultHandler2`, but because the eception is thrown on the method itself, I cannot see a way to do this.

Is there one? Or am I stuck with the original exception?

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace of the exception you wish to catch

Comment: @alexbt: My class is embedded in a CLI OSGi framework, as a bundle, so I cannot properly control error handling, what I do get is `[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.`

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by setting my extension of `DefaultHandler2` as the error handler to the XML parser's XML reader, as got via `parser.getXMLReader()` (`org.xml.sax.XMLReader` has a method `setErrorHandler(ErrorHandler errorHandler)`...

Overriding `public void fatalError(SAXParseException e)`, I can handle the fatal error.